# Success/Failed callback room operations

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm from iOS world and I new in Android development.
My problem is this:

I working on Android app where I have to save data in local database.
For this reason I choose Room classes for this.
In iOS, the Room equivalent, is CoreData and when I do some operation by it (for example insert or delete operations) I have two callbacks: one for sucess and other for failed.

I dont see this in Room system, but I can do insert operation and 
I don't know when this operation has ended and above all if it went well or failed.

For now I create simply the Dao and Database class (and one entity)

```
public abstract class LuxuryAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase
{
   public abstract DatabaseLocale dbDao();
}

@Dao
public interface DatabaseLocale
{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public void insertChat(ArrayList<Lobby> chats);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Lobby")
    List<Lobby> getAllUserChat();

    @Query("DELETE FROM Lobby")
    public void deleteAllLoobies();
}
```

I would like to do similar to onClickListener for example.

I call insert query and I have a listener that has two methods: success and failed.

You could help me figure out where I'm wrong and if it's possible to do something like that?

Comment: You can use Android `Cursor` if you want the report.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367184/how-to-check-if-data-is-inserted-in-room-database

Comment: can you explain better please?

Comment: Actually Room is a new API. The backbone of Room architecture is database and cursor. Before this API we used cursor for database operation. You can use it also for better flexibility. Because you are using a pre-populated database and Room architecture doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have your insert return a Long, which represents the autogenerated id for the entry:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
public long insertChat(ArrayList<Lobby> chats);
```

Also, Room will generally fast fail on any errors - meaning it throw an exception.  Your method calling into Room should handle any error exception as needed.

Comment: sorry I dont understand. You say that the method insertChat I have to put it in try/catch block?

Comment: I dont have autogenerated primary key, but are string fields

Comment: No, it is already in a try-catch block. The main problem of the insert operation is it is performing in a background thread.

Comment: by words I dont uderstand. If I do insert method, how Do I catch some errors (memory, general error ecc..)?

Comment: I would like to know when the insert call is ended. For example I want to do some operations at the end of the insert call

Comment: As soon as the function returns it has completed.  This is why you need to call database methods on a background thread - they happen synchronously.